# Копирование словаря с вложенным списком и кортежем

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, tuple

**Основной вопрос:**
Почему в копии словаря 'new_var' значение словаря 'var' в индексе '[0]', 'list', меняется, а в '[1]', 'tuple', нет?
Ведь оба параметра в данном примере идут как вложения и что бы они не менялись, нужно использовать 'deepcopy'. В чем моя ошибка?

Весь код:

```
var = {'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar', )}
new_var = var.copy()
var.update({'str': 'string'})
var['list'].append ([True, False])
var['tuple'] += ('baz', )
```

Идем пошагово.

Есть словарь:

```
var = {'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar', )}
```

Создаем его копию (не глубокую):

```
new_var = var.copy()
```

Делаем 'var.update'

```
var.update({'str': 'string'})
```

Получаем 'var' и 'new_var':

```
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar'), 'str': 'string'}
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar')}
```

'var' обновился со значением '{'str': 'string'}',
а 'new_var' остался без изменений, т.к. это копия.

Далее делаем '.append':

```
var['list'].append ([True, False])
```

Получаем 'var' и 'new_var':

```
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar'), 'str': 'string'}
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar')}
```

**Первый вопрос:** Почему значение листа '[True, False]' было перенесено в копию 'new_var'?
*(Полагаю потому, что это вложение в виде ссылки)*

Далее добавляем пункт в 'tuple':

```
var['tuple'] += ('baz', )
```

Получаем 'var' и 'new_var':

```
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), 'str': 'string'}
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]], 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar')}
```

**Второй вопрос:** Почему в этом случае 'baz' добавилось только в словарь 'var', но не в его копию 'new_var', как это было в прошлом пункте?

P.S. Вероятно, мой вопрос глупый, я только учусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что `tuple` в Python является неизменяемым (immutable) объектом . Поэтому для кортежей не существует метода `.append()` и   вам пришлось заменить значение по ключу `"tuple"` ссылкой на **новый** кортеж.

Ваш пример:

```
Out[321]:
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]],
 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar'),
 'str': 'string'}

In [322]: id(var["tuple"])
Out[322]: 140364687889408

In [323]: var['tuple'] += ('baz', )

In [324]: id(var["tuple"])
Out[324]: 140364687888704  # <--- обратите внимание на изменившийся `id` !

In [325]: var
Out[325]:
{'list': [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]],
 'tuple': ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'),
 'str': 'string'}

In [326]: id(new_var["tuple"])
Out[326]: 140364687889408  # <-- new_var["tuple"] все еще указывает на кортеж __до__ изменения
```

---

`var['tuple'] += ('baz', )` эквивалентно:

```
var['tuple'] = var['tuple'] + ('baz', )
```

А `var['tuple'] + ('baz', )` создает новый кортеж с результатом сложения.

Comment: Т.е. получается в словаре 'var' мы не редактировали, а заменили индекс [1], tuple.
А в копии 'new_var' остались старые значения?
И причиной этому неизменяемый тип объекта?

Comment: @StiffStifler, обновил ответ